# How to deploy a pointed CMMN file to a pointed process engine in Camunda?

Tags: camunda

The document shows me how to create ProcessEngineConfiguration and ProcessEngine, and then it shows me how to modify process instances. I don't know how to manage my process and case defintion files with Repositoryservice. Is there any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways of deploying your diagrams to the engine.

The easiest is to have a ProcessApplication on the classpath and a processes.xml file in src/main/resources/META-INF (con be empty). Camunda will then scan your library and deploy all processes on startup.

Second option, though I personally would not advise you to, is that you use the [engine-spring](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/user-guide/spring-framework-integration/) module and activate  auto-deployment

And as a third option, you can still deploy manually by using either `repositoryService.createDeployment().addClasspathResource(...).deploy()` or use the rest api.